# How do you cancel a drop command with Drag & Drop

Tags: drag-and-drop, silverlight-toolkit, silverlight-5.0

How do you go about cancelling a drop event using the latest Silverlight Toolkit Drag and Drop framework?  I'd assume this has to be stupid, but I don't seem to be able to find any valid information to get me to the right place.

Any guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Within the drag operation you can set:

```
e.Handled = True
e.cancel = True
```

You can set these on drag over as well. But you can also do a similar thing within the drop operation.

Answer (score 0):

1. `AllowDrop="False"`
2. Do nothing in drop handler

Comment: Actually, wanted to within the "drop" event or similar say "Hey, Cancel doing this" based on business logic.